# Is it possible to return a CustomMetaData in a @HttpGet?

Tags: metadata

Is it possible to return a CustomMetaData? I'm getting the error "HttpGet methods do not support return type of InsPackages.Wrapper" when I added "customMetadata" codes on my class. Here's my code:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/api/PackageLicense')
global with sharing class InsPackages{
    @HttpGet    
    global static Wrapper doGet(){
        Wrapper wrap = new Wrapper();
        List<PackageLicense> packageList = [SELECT NamespacePrefix, Status, CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate FROM PackageLicense];
        List<Publisher> publisherList = [SELECT Name, MajorVersion, MinorVersion, NamespacePrefix FROM Publisher];
        Metadata.CustomMetadata customMetadata =  new Metadata.CustomMetadata();
        Metadata.CustomMetadataValue customField = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();
        for(PackageLicense p : packageList){
            customField.field = 'NamespacePrefix';
            customField.value = p.NamespacePrefix;
            customMetadata.values.add(customField);
        }
        wrap.customMetadata = customMetadata;
        return wrap;
    }    
    global class Wrapper{
        public List<Metadata.CustomMetadataValue> customMetadata {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your question, the documentation states the following:

> You can use user-defined types for parameters in your Apex REST
>   methods. Apex REST deserializes request data into public, private, or
>   global class member variables of the user-defined type, unless the
>   variable is declared as static or transient. (...) Note that the
>   public, private, or global class member **variables must be types
>   allowed by Apex REST:**
>
> - Apex primitives (excluding sObject and Blob).
> - sObjects
> - Lists or maps of Apex primitives or sObjects (only maps with String keys are supported).
>
> When creating user-defined types used as Apex REST method parameters,
>   avoid introducing any class member variable definitions that result in
>   cycles (definitions that depend on each other) at run time in your
>   user-defined types.

And Custom Metadata is none of the before.

In any case, I think what you actually want to return is a simple `Map`:

```
global class Wrapper {
    public Map<String, String> PackageInformation { get; set; }

    public Wrapper() {
        PackageInformation = new Map<String,String>();
    }
}
```

Which you want to populate in the following way:

```
    for(PackageLicense p : packageList){
        PackageInformation.put('NamespacePrefix', p.NamespacePrefix);
    }
```

Comment: Hi @javier-garcía-manzano . 
I forgot to mention that I was trying to combine the details of the installed packages in my org. Aside from the information from the object 'PackageLicense', I need to grab the Name, MajorVersion & MinorVersion of the package from the Publisher object. And that's the reason why I wanted to use CustomMetadata. 
Can I still use Metadata with this? and use Mapping in order to return it?

Comment: Hi @cookie. No problem. The answer is still valid: if you re-read it you will see that Custom Metadata is not a valid type for REST web services, as the documentation states. You may only use Salesfore Objects and Apex primitive types paired with collections.